# undefined reference to `strtok_r' Windows 10 MinGW

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

i am always getting error while compile , it's saying undefined reference to `strtok_r' i am using MinGW in windows 10 , please help to solve this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  char *test1, *test2;
  char *state1, *state2;
  char *cur1, *cur2;

  test1 = malloc(20);
  test2 = malloc(20);
  strcpy(test1, "a,b,c,d");
  strcpy(test2, "e,f,g,h");

  cur1 = strtok_r(test1, ",", &state1);
  cur2 = strtok_r(test2, ",", &state2);
  while (cur1 != NULL && cur2 != NULL) {
    if (cur1 != NULL) {
      printf("cur1 : %s\n", cur1);
    }
    if (cur2 != NULL) {
      printf("cur2 : %s\n", cur2);
    }
    cur1 = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &state1);
    cur2 = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &state2);
  };
}
```

Here is error and warning messages in windows 10

```
strtok-test.c: In function 'main':
strtok-test.c:16:10: warning: implicit declaration of function 'strtok_r' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   cur1 = strtok_r(test1, ",", &state1);
          ^~~~~~~~
strtok-test.c:16:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   cur1 = strtok_r(test1, ",", &state1);
        ^
strtok-test.c:17:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
   cur2 = strtok_r(test2, ",", &state2);
        ^
strtok-test.c:25:10: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     cur1 = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &state1);
          ^
strtok-test.c:26:10: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     cur2 = strtok_r(NULL, ",", &state2);
      ^
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\ccvzdBJh.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\Desktop\New folder/strtok-test.c:16: undefined reference to `strtok_r'
C:\Users\Desktop\New folder/strtok-test.c:17: undefined reference to `strtok_r'
C:\Users\Desktop\New folder/strtok-test.c:25: undefined reference to `strtok_r'
C:\Users\Desktop\New folder/strtok-test.c:26: undefined reference to `strtok_r'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you for asking , i added the code please have a look

Comment: This isn't, strictly speaking, an answer to your question, but I would highly recommend that you incorporate some open source variation of the (non-standard) strsep function, which can be found in glibc and all of the BSD's libc's. It is vastly superior to strtok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtok_r is not a standard C method (it is POSIX). Your compiler may not be POSIX compliant and therefore its standard library might not contain the method. Look in your string.h file and see whether its prototype is declared there.